# ximgproc (opencv-contrib sub-module) installed successfully but i am getting AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.6, importerror, opencv-contrib

I installed `opencv-contrib` that has `ximgproc` as a sub-module, using this:

```py
pip install opencv_python-3.2.0+contrib-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

when I run  below lines:

```py
import cv2

# ...

right_matcher = cv2.ximgproc.createRightMatcher(left_matcher)
```

I am getting this error:

```py
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'ximgproc'
```

How can I use `ximgproc` functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed openCV and the separate contrib module via
`pip install opencv-python opencv-contrib-python`.
That worked fine for me. If there is no reason why you want to install openCV manually you could try that.

See here for the installation instructions on the [GitHub repo of opencv-python](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python#installation-and-usage)